# Grails: avoid browser checks when click on button

Tags: validation, grails, button

In my *Grails* project, I would like to use a button to jump on another page while I'm in creation of an entity.

Here is the code for the button:

```
<button href="${createLink(controller: 'myController', action: 'create')}">
```

The problem is that, clicking on that button, if I'm in creation of some entity, it performs checks on form (I see a popup below a field telling me that I need to select an element from dropdown)

How can I jump to create of another entity while I am *creating / modifying* another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an anchor tag instead of a button:

```
<a href="${createLink(controller: 'myController', action: 'create')}">Some other create page</a>
```